# Remove margins between rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove margins between hello and dd how could i do it.

```
<div className="container border border-primary">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="">A </div>
            <div className="col">
                <div className="row justify-content-between m-0 p-0">
                    <p>hello</p>
                    <p>hello</p>
                </div>
                <div className='row m-0 p-0'>
                    dd
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the margin of the `<p>` elements to remove the space between the rows.

**You have three possibilities to solve this:**

- Using Bootstrap utility class [`.m-0`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/) on the `<p>` elements itself.
- A custom CSS rule to remove the `margin` of the `<p>` elements.
- Using a `<span>` element instead of a `<p>` element.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container border border-primary">
  <div class="row">
    <div>A</div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row justify-content-between m-0 p-0">
        <p class="m-0">hello</p>
        <p class="m-0">hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class='row m-0 p-0'>dd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes p elems were giving spaces by default. Thank you Sir

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.no-gutters` from the Bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#no-gutters).

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.no-gutters` doesn't work here since he don't want to remove the space between columns. He want to remove the space between "hello" and "dd" (vertical) *"I want to remove margins between hello and dd"*.